# Showing Customized Data on Google Maps Marker (Similar to Instagram Photo Map)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Google Maps API, and have been looking for ways to customize the markers. The API provided only allows me to change icons but what I actually need is to pass HTML content to the marker. I want to pass some data e.g.*numbers* to the marker, and when user clicks the marker, more details will show inside infoWindow. (something like [this website](http://weatherhopper.com/#))

At first, I thought it would be something like Instagram Photo Map, you have a summary of photos within a region. But then I realize that's more like a markerClusterer which simply counts the total number of markers within the range (correct me if I'm wrong).

I still couldn't find any way to display customized data on the marker. Is there any plugin I can use if no default API available?

P.S. first time posting a question, hope it's clear! highly appreciate your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you see on the linked map are not real `google.maps.Markers`, you see [Custom Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays). With a custom overlay you may draw any HTML-content on the map, e.g. these labels.

You may either use the build-in methods to draw these overlays, or use a library like [infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can customise markers using [styledmarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/docs/examples.html) library. This library is used to create Markers that can be styled in different ways, such as changing the color or shape, or adding text labels. Below is an example of how to use this library with XML.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
      var text = markers[i].getAttribute("text");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
     var styleMaker = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{color:"00ff00",text:text}),position:myLatLng,map:map});
```

}

I have a [DEMO](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/test/viewmarkers.html) using this with a database of 2 tables state centroids and cities in USA using XML . The marker shows the state and number of cities in state.